# MySQL: Joining a joint table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have three tables

Question
ID | question_name

This table lists a number of questions, each question has there id.

Location
ID | location_name

This question lists a number of locations, each location has its ID

Question_Location
ID | question_id | location_ID

This question matches the question to location on the basis of the key.

How would I create a table that provides me with: 
question_name | location_name

Where each question is matched to its location but instead of seeing the IDs I see the question_name and location_name.

I could join the location and the question_location table and the question_location table and the location table but I don't manage to put it together so that I have the output as described.

Comment: if Vladmir or myself helped you could you please mark them as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select q.Question_Name, l.location_name
from Question q
Inner join Question_Location ql on ql.Question_id = q.question_id
inner join Location l on l.location_id = ql.location_id
```

Assuming that every question has a location and not null, if that's the case you will be better with a left join on the location join.

Comment: in "Select q.Question_Name" what does the "q" refer to?

Comment: The q is an alias, notice next to where I call the question table I place a q. This is so when you have multiple tables I a query you can reference it through the alias.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
SELECT q.question_name, l.location_name
FROM Question_Location ql
LEFT JOIN Question q on ql.question_id = q.ID
LEFT JOIN Location l ON ql.location_ID = l.ID
;
```

Comment: when you write "q.question_name", what does the "q" relate to?

Comment: It is a alias for table Question.